# Android Devices Timezone Incorrectly returns GMT (00:00) always with rawOffset of 0

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, utc, gmt

The past couple of days have been a nightmare where I even considered uninstalling then reinstalling Android Studio just to see if my build was the issue.

An app i'm doing requires a timestamp in a picture and the timestamp must show the Timezone as well. 
I tried the usual

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
```

method and for all the android test devices i have , all were returning GMT 00:00 . I spent 2 days trying to find out why all stackOveflow examples dont work and thought it must be my build because even changing timezone on device still resulted in GMT time returned.
Before I uninstalled I came across the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. The answer i found was aimed at another question but it worked for me.
First set the Timezone to Null and after that the correct device timezone is picked. 
If on emulator though, timezone will remain UTC.

```
        TimeZone.setDefault(null);
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "");
        TimeZone.setDefault(null);

        //get Calendar instance
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        //get current TimeZone using getTimeZone method of Calendar class
        TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();

        //display current TimeZone using getDisplayName() method of TimeZone class
        String strTimeZone=timeZone.getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT);
        long lngTimeZoneOffset= timeZone.getRawOffset();
```

I hope this saves someone days of hair pulling.